# Apple isn't accepting applications built with this version of SDK (10.7.1)

Tags: xcode, macos, osx-lion

I updated to OS X 10.7.1 yesterday. After that, Xcode has been saying, whenever I try to upload a Mac app to the App Store, that Apple isn't accepting applications built with this version of the SDK.

I am 100% sure I have the lastest Xcode (4.1, build 4B110), as I have even completely uninstalled Xcode and reinstalled again from the Mac App Store. This happens with all 3 projects I tried to upload.

Architectures are set to 32/64-bit Intel, and Base SDK is Latest Mac OS X (10.7).

Hope any of you can help me,

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried asking at the developer forums?  They might just need a little time to update the App Store submission process.

Comment: You were right, Brad. Please post that as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a temporary issue, just like Brad said.